# suggest a postgres tool to find the difference between the schema and the data

Tags: postgresql

Dear all , 
 
Can any one suggest me the postgres tool for linux which is used to find  the 
difference between the 2 given database

I tried with the apgdiff 2.3 but it gives the difference in terms of schema not the data
but I need both ! 

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing data is not easy especially if your database is huge. I created Python program that can dump PostgreSQL data schema to file that can be easily compared via 3rd party diff programm: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576557-dump-postgresql-db-schema-to-text/?in=user-186902

I think that this program can be extended by dumping all tables data into separate CSV files, similar to those used by PostgreSQL `COPY` command. Remember to add the same `ORDER BY` in `SELECT ...` queries. I have created tool that reads `SELECT` statements from file and saves results in separate files. This way I can manage which tables and fields I want to compare (not all fields can be used in `ORDER BY`, and not all are important for me). Such configuration can be easily created using "dump schema" utility.

Comment: Often you don't need to compare all data. Often you just want to compare look up tables which takes away most of the data volume issues of having to compare two 6TB tables for instance. Of course this isn't always the case.

Comment: Of course you are right. Idea to not compare whole database data lead me to tool I described in 2nd paragraph: execute select statements from file and save output to csv.

Answer (score 2):

Check out dbsolo [DBSOLO](http://www.dbsolo.com). It does both object and data compares and can create a sync script based on the results.  It's free to try and $99 to buy. My guess is the 99 bucks will be money well spent to avoid trying to come up with your own software to do this.

Data Compare
http://www.dbsolo.com/help/datacomp.html

Object Compare
http://www.dbsolo.com/help/compare.html

Comment: There are some other products which can do the job. I tried DBSOLO, and DataSync too (www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/datasync/)

Answer (score 0):

apgdiff https://www.apgdiff.com/
It's an opensource solution. I used it before for checking differences between differences in dumps. Quite useful

[EDIT]
It's for differenting by schema only

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your answer to make it more accessible: How does your solution work, and why? Explain, why it is *quite usuful*. And please also cite the relevant parts for the question from the website you linked.